# Using the Swift Contacts Framework

Tags: ios, swift, contacts-framework

When the app has access to the devices contacts, and you need those contacts to populate a `PickerView`, does it pull the contacts to a `Firebase DB` and fetch those contacts to populate the `PickerView`? Or does it do it within the phone(maybe `Core Data`)?

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

If does and I can use `Core Data`, can I use it hand in hand with `Firebase`, or does it even store it somewhere? I'd like my users to be able to select which contacts they want to add to the app.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The contacts _is_ a database. It _already_ provides the ability to populate a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to pull from the device's Contacts, using the [Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts) - in `Xcode` this is the `Contacts.framework` package. The Apple site offers some sample code that you might be able to take advantage of in your application. For that you'd need permission from the user by enabling a `NSContactsUsageDescription` in your `info.plist`. That describes to the user why you'd need access to their contacts.

As far as storing the data in a Database, I'm not sure that would be a wise decision nor one that makes sense. Consider the reasoning behind that, does this information need to be on some remote database? if your answer is no, then chances are that you don't need to do that extra work. You might however register new users that use your application with something like Google's `Firebase` if you want to manage any messages between users (for a chat app for example).

Hopefully that answers your question and helps you out in some way.

Comment: Thank you. I am using firebase for new user registrations as well as the db for other items. Just wasn't sure about the contacts. So the contacts framework will allow me to pull the contacts, what ever information i need, and input it into my pickerview, without me having to store the contacts anywhere?

Comment: It should do that. Take a look at the docs on the Apple site. And see if there's not a sample project somewhere online, so you can see how it all works together.

Comment: Excellent! that just gives me a direction to go. I appreciate it very much!